# Javascript - SweetAlert plugin - draw textbox inside

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert2

I am really new to this with Javascript and i have been trying to find an answer for if its possible to add an textbox inside SweetAlert JS.
I have today some text and some buttons and works just fine.
But i would like to add an Yellow textbox inside the pop-up with some black text inside like an warning state.

Is this possible to do inside this script?

[image: alert sample image]

```
var Functions;
(function(Functions) {
    var MyNamespace;
    (function(MyNamespace) {
        function PopUp_UnloadRecipe(OutputSignal, TextHeaderDialog1, TextContentDialog1, TextHeaderDialog2, TextContentDialog2, TextButton1Dialog1) {

            Swal.fire({
                title: TextHeaderDialog1,
                showClass: {
                    popup: 'animate__animated animate__fadeInDown'
                },
                hideClass: {
                    popup: 'animate__animated animate__fadeOutUp'
                },
                html: TextContentDialog1,
                icon: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                backdrop: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)',
                allowOutsideClick: false,
                allowEscapeKey: false,
                footer: '<b><H1>WARNING!</H1></b>',

                confirmButtonText: TextButton1Dialog1
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.value) {
                    Swal.fire(
                        TextHeaderDialog2,
                        TextContentDialog2,
                        'success'
                    )
                    OutputSignal.write(true);
                }
            });
        }
      
        MyNamespace.PopUp_UnloadRecipe = PopUp_UnloadRecipe;
      
    })(MyNamespace = Functions.MyNamespace || (Functions.MyNamespace = {}));
  
    Functions.registerFunctionEx('PopUp_UnloadRecipe', 'TcHmi.Functions.MyNamespace', MyNamespace.PopUp_UnloadRecipe);
})(Functions = TcHmi.Functions || (TcHmi.Functions = {}));
})(TcHmi);
```

Comment: Where is you mock-up for your alert? Please show the HTML/JavaScript/CSS code.

Comment: As @Mr.Polywhirl mentioned, you will need to add minimal reproducible code for others to run your code and help find a solution to your problem. Show us what you've already tried and you will no doubt get an answer that helps you with your problem.

Comment: Sorry my first add in here but i have tried to add the code above now.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly add input boxes to your pop-ups. For this, I would recommend migrating over to sweetheart 2 where you'll find more functionality along with better documentation.

1. documentation: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples
   (I would look specifically at the ajax request example)
2. Example:

```
Swal.fire({
    title: 'Enter some example text',
    input: 'text',
    inputAttributes: {
        autocapitalize: 'off'
    },
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Look up',
})
```